# data was not visible on browser when using handlebar.js

Tags: handlebars.js

I was implementing handlebar.js for my sample  app.As per the handlebar.js documentation, it tried with the example as mentioned. But the values are loaded on the dom inside the script, but not visible on browser.

**HTML**

```
<body>
<h1>Handlebar</h1>
<script id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
<div class="entry">
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  <div class="body">
    {{body}}
  </div>
</div>
</script>
<script  src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script  src="js/handlebars.js"></script>
<script  src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

**app.js**

```
var source   = $("#entry-template").html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
var context = {title: "My New Post", body: "This is my first post!"}
var html    = template(context);
$("#entry-template").html(template(context));
```

When the browser gets loaded i am getting a blank screen, but while debugging via firebug able to find the values title and body

Answer (score 6):

You're replacing the content of a `<script>` element:

```
$("#entry-template").html(template(context));
```

and `#entry-template` is a `<script>`:

```
<script id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
```

Browsers don't display the content of `<script>`s with that `type`. You want to put your filled in template into something like a `<div>` that will be displayed:

```
<h1>Handlebar</h1>
<div id="html-goes-here"></div>
```

and then:

```
$("#html-goes-here").html(template(context));
```